# Oberbegriff für Medizin, Biologie, Psychologie, Philosophie, etc

Tags: single-word-request

Gibt es einen Obegriff, der all diese Themenbereiche umfasst. Es geht um einen Begriff für einen Bereich einer speziellen Universität.

Psychologie
Philosophie
Medizin
Ergotherapie
Pflege
Ernährungswissenschaften
Sportwissenschaften
Hebamme
Zahnmedizin
Mikrobiologie
Neurologie
Optik
Tiermedizin
Pharmazie

Bisherige Ideen waren "Mensch (es ist aber auch Tiermedizin dabei)", "Naturwissenschaften (aber keine Physik, Chemie, etc.)", "Soziales (doch darunter fallen dann eher tatsächliche Sozialberufe)"

Note: 
evtl. würde ich Philosophie auch in den Bereich Kultur & Gesellschaft geben.

Comment: Ja, Philosophie passt gar nicht zum Rest; *klinische Wissenschaften*?

Comment: oder gesundhheitsbezogene Wissenschaften? Philosophie passt in der Tat nicht hinein. Es wird nicht vom Begriff erfasst, wirkt aber auch überhaupt im Portfolio der Universität irgendwie wie ein Fremdkörper.

Comment: Geht es darum, diesem Strauß von Fächern jeder Hochschule einen gemeinsamen Oberbegriff zu geben? Sind das alle Fächer, die dort gelehrt werden, oder ist es wirkliche eine Universität (mit universalem Fächerreigen)?

Answer (score 1):

Für mich passt der Begriff *Lebenswissenschaften* (Life Sciences) am besten.

Zwar liegt im Zentrum der Lebenswissenschaften die Biologie, aber sie umfassen eben auch die anderen in der Frage genannten Disziplinen.

Comment: Für mein Verständnis ist "Lebenswissenschaften" als Übertragung von "Live Sciences" hauptsächlich in Gebrauch für die modernen Dinge rund um Molekularbiologie und Genetik. Dass die allgemeine Medizin auch unter "Live Sciences" fällt, wäre zwar eigentlich logisch, ist mir aber bisher nicht untergekommen. (Ich bin aber kein Lebenswissenschaftler.)

Comment: Ich stimme dir zu. Aber mangels Alternativen ist das vermutlich derjenige Begriff, der dem "Strauß von Fächern" am nächsten kommt, wenn nicht dem Gebrauch nach, dann zumindest aus sprachlogischer Sicht. Am besten wäre wohl ein völlig neuer Begriff.

Comment: Man sagt "Life sciences" (nicht "Live....")

Answer (score 0):

Nach längerem Grübeln darüber, was den Strauß von Fächern verbindet, komme ich darauf, dass es bei allen eigentlich um die Steigerung oder Stabilisierung des Wohlbefindens von Lebewesen geht. Darum schlage ich vor, dass Du Deine Universität

> Universität für Wohlbefinden

nennst.

Die medizinischen und therapeutischen Fächer sind klar gesundheitsorientiert; Ernährung ebenfalls; Sport geht auch in diese Richtung (oder behauptet es jedenfalls); Tiermedizin hat lediglich andere Patienten; bei Optik besteht Unsicherheit (es könnte ja eine rein physikalische Optik gemeint sein, also z.B. das Bauen von Teleskopen), aber im Kontext der anderen  Fächer will ich mal annehmen, dass es irgendwie ums menschliche Auge und vielleicht Hilfen für dessen Gebrauch im Alltag geht. Mikrobiologie als Lehre von kleinen Organismen bezieht sich hier vermutlich auf deren Zusammenspiel mit den größeren Organismen (Menschen, Tiere) und passt insofern ins Bild. Auch Philosophie lässt sich leicht als eine Wissenschaft vom Wohlbefinden deuten: Es geht um kognitive, mentale und von mir aus spirituelle Orientierung, deren Antrieb letztlich ist, das Wohlbefinden des philosophierenden Subjekts zu steigern.

Hübsch fände ich auch

> Universität für Wohlsein

Oder du willst es etwas wissenschaftlicher. Dann vielleicht

> Universität für psychische und physische Gesundheit

Comment: Au ja. Da mache ich dann meinen _Dr. h.c. of Immortality_ ;-).

Comment: Und bei Informatik geht es darum, das Wohlbefinden des programmierenden Subjekts zu steigern? Mit derartigen Interpretationen kann man alles und nichts mit dem Begriff fassen.

Comment: @userunknown Wie kommen Sie auf Informatik? Die ist doch gar nicht in der Auflistung.

Comment: Würde aber mit der Argumentation problemlos dazu passen. "Steigerung oder Stabilisierung des Wohlbefindens" hat mit Philosophie auch nicht mehr zu tun. Oder Optik. Die Annahme, es ginge nur um Brillen und Kontaktlinsen kann man mit Medizininformatik aufziehen. Philosophie, Sport und Optik haben mit Gesundheit nicht notwendig zu tun.